# MIPS recursion call in loop, preserving loop variable

Tags: loops, assembly, recursion, stack, mips

I'm converting the following recursive java program to MIPS asm. The algorithm computes all the possible ordering/permutations of the numbers. But the recursive call is in the for loop. I need to preserve the variable 'i' in my MIPS version but I don't know exactly where to add that. My algorithm is correct, it's just that my $t0 (which is 'i') never gets reset to 0. I just can't figure out how/where to preserve it on the stack or when to take it off the stack. Any help appreciated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test 
{
    private static void swap(int[] v, int i, int j) 
    {
        int t = v[i]; 
        v[i] = v[j]; 
        v[j] = t;
    }

    public void permute(int[] v, int n) 
    {
        if (n == 1) 
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
        else 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {
                permute(v, n-1);
                if (n % 2 == 1) 
                    swap(v, 0, n-1);
                else 
                    swap(v, i, n-1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] ns = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        new Test().permute(ns, ns.length);
    }
```

}

and the mips function
Note: I am permutating Strings, not integers but the algorithm is the same.

```
#----------------------------------------------
# anagram - Prints all the permutations of 
# the given word
#     a0 - the word to compute the anagrams
#     s0 - n, the length of the word
#     a1 - n - 1 (length-1)
#----------------------------------------------
anagram:
addi $sp, $sp, -16

sw $a0, 0($sp)
sw $a1, 4($sp)
sw $s0, 8($sp)
sw $ra, 12($sp)

add $s0, $a1, $zero         # this is n

addi $a1, $s0, -1           # n-1
beq $s0, 1, printS
init: move $t0, $zero       # t0 = i = 0
logic: slt $t1, $t0, $s0        # Set t1 = 1 if t0 < length
       beqz $t1, endAnagram     # if it's zero, it's the end of the loop

jal anagram

li $t2, 2
div $s0, $t2
mfhi $t3

beqz $t3, even          # if even branch to even, otherwise it will go to odd
odd: # swap the n-1 char with the first
add $t4, $a0, $zero
add $t5, $a0, $a1

lb $t6, 0($t4)          # first char
lb $t7, 0($t5)          # n-1 char

sb $t7, 0($t4)          # swap the two
sb $t6, 0($t5)

j inc # skip the even section

even: # swap the ith char with n-1 char
add $t4, $a0, $t0           # ith char
add $t5, $a0, $a1           # n-1 char

lb $t6, 0($t4)          # ith char
lb $t7, 0($t5)          # n-1 char

sb $t7, 0($t4)          # swap the two
sb $t6, 0($t5)

inc: addi $t0, $t0, 1           # t0++;
j logic

endAnagram:
# reset stack pointers
lw $a0, 0($sp)
lw $a1, 4($sp)
lw $s0, 8($sp)
lw $ra, 12($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 16           # adjust stack
jr $ra

printS: # print string and jump to return
   jal printString # calls printString function which prints the string

   j endAnagram
```

Answer (score 1):

`$t0` is not preserved accross subroutine calls according to convention, and you seem to follow that convention. As such, you have two choices:

1. you either store `i` in a register that is preserved, in which case
   you need to preserve the register yourself in the prologue/epilogue. You already do this for `$s0`.
2. or you save `$t0` yourself on the stack, around the subroutine call

In both cases, you will need additional space for your locals, so change `addi $sp, $sp, -16` to `addi $sp, $sp, -20` (along with the matching code in the epilogue too). If you choose option #1, use for example `$s1` to store `i`. Add code to save and restore `$s1` just like you do for `$s0`. If you choose option #2, add code around the `jal anagram` that writes `$t0` to stack before the `jal`, and reloads it after.